# What happens to the metro screen when I join Windows 8 PC to a domain?

Tags: windows-8, domain

Most companies have domains and all PCs there will be connected to these domains. Most of these domains do not offer internet connectivity or limited connectivity for security or other reasons. What happens to that dynamic metro screen which is useless without internet? Actually will it even be there after joining a domain or there will only be the desktop? is it something the network administrator can control?

Maybe I just can not imagine the shiny metro style screen joined to a domain at work...

Comment: I have never seen a DOMAIN that restricts internet access outside of the standard web filters... but for the sake of argument..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Modern UI** screen does not alter in any way when it is placed on a domain.

**CAVEATS**

Windows Server 2012's group policies can affect the Start screen functionality as needed.

If internet connectivity is not available then any dependent live tiles or apps will simply cease to function (in the same was as if you unplugged the network cable out the back).

The live tiles will just time out. You can also just right click and disable any live tiles you wish. then there are no active elements for the tiles to call anyway

Comment: When you unplug your home PC it will be temporary.. and the its expected to connect again. But at work it will be disconnected forever. So most of the metro style active thing is dead!

Comment: yes. very true. but it will not freak out any more or less than that. Service just simply wont be restored and the live tiles will just time out.

You can also just right click and disable any live tiles you wish. then there are no active elements for the tiles to call anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The metro screen will still be available after connecting Windows 8 to a domain. If there is no internet connectivity, the tiles for various metro apps will not update to reflect any changes.  You have control over what tiles are displayed, so you can always just remove from the display the tiles for the apps which require the internet to be useful and replace these with tiles to apps you actually use, including desktop apps.  The icons may or may not be sized correctly or may be pixelated, but they will still work as launchers.